# Pyspark how to loop through a directory fetch files and count number of rows

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to loop through an hdfs directory and its sub-directorates for csv files and count number of rows in each file.
I am trying the following code snippet but it keep throwing me error "IllegalArgumentException: 'Pathname /hdfs:/data/msd from /hdfs:/data/msd is not a valid DFS filename.'"

```
hadoop = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop
fs = hadoop.fs.FileSystem
conf = hadoop.conf.Configuration() 
path = hadoop.fs.Path("/hdfs:///data/msd")

for f in fs.get(conf).listStatus(path):
    print(f.getPath(), f.getLen())
```

[image]

Comment: remove `/hdfs://`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the first slash from your path. It should be `hdfs:///data/msd` instead